# What is cold observable in context of angular HttpClient

Tags: rxjs, angular-httpclient

While using angular `HttpClient` of angular I got to know that HttpClient post method used cold observable and will make 2 separate calls to post data to the server.And also unless you will not subscribe the post method it will not post data to the server.

Although, `Rxjs` cold observable says it will hold all the sequence until the the end and fire all when it subscribed.

How it will make 2 separate call to server to post data.

Answer (score 2):

COLD is when your observable creates the producer

```
// COLD
var cold = new Observable((observer) => {
  var producer = new Producer();
  // have observer listen to producer here
});
```

HOT is when your observable closes over the producer

```
// HOT
var producer = new Producer();
var hot = new Observable((observer) => {
  // have observer listen to producer here
});
```

source: https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this behavior is caused by the use of observables.

Rather I suspect that the browser is issuing a pre-flight OPTIONS request as a 'handshake' with the server to determine whether the CORS protocol is understood. This precedes the POST request and is possibly why you get 2 calls to the server to post data.