# Observable.subscribe() vs Promise with async/await

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

Consider the following two methods in a `Service` for querying a webservice:

```
getAssessmentById(id: number): Observable<MotorAssessorReport> {
  const url = environment.endPoints.assessment.base + 
    environment.endPoints.assessment.assessmentById + id;
  return this.httpClient.get<MotorAssessorReport>(url)
}

async getAssessmentByIdAsync(id: number): Promise<MotorAssessorReport> {
  const url = environment.endPoints.assessment.base + 
    environment.endPoints.assessment.assessmentById + id;
   const data = await this.httpClient.get<MotorAssessorReport>(url).toPromise();
  return data;
}
```

The first method, `getAssessmentById` returns an `observable`.  The second method, `getAssessmentByIdAsync`, returns a `promise`.

```
subscribeToAssessment() {
 this.assessmentService.getAssessmentById(this.assessmentId).subscribe(result => 
 {
    this.assessment = result;
 });
}

async fetchAssessment() {
  this.assessment = await this.assessmentService.getAssessmentByIdAsync(this.assessmentId);
}
```

I have always been using the first approach, returning an `Observable<T>`, and subscribing in my calling code.

I recently truely began to understand that this approach should only really be used if you expect multiple results to be returned.  In other words, when using a `Promise<T>`, the maximum amount the callback is called, is only once.

Since I have been expecting my server to only always be returning once, is my approach wrong, and should I rather be using the `Promise<T>` approach, combined with `async/await`?

Comment: NB: you're over-using async/await. You achieve the same with a normal function that returns the promise.

Comment: I thought I might be.  When would be a suitable time to use them?

Comment: When you need to perform an action after having the resolved promise in order the somehow finalise the value you want to return -- this could include awaiting another promise -- then use `await`. But when you are just interested in returning a promise just like you get it, then no `async/await` is needed.

Comment: I posted simplified code here, but I do in my case require the await, as I need execution to stop (be awaited) untill the "assessment" property is set.

Answer (score 6):

- If you are using the service to get values continuously, use an observable.
- If you need the data to be fetched only once, use a promise. You need to unsubscribe to an observable or else it would cause a memory leak.
- Use async await only if necessary, in case your code creates a callback mess.

Answer (score 5):

I think you also have to remember the difference between hot and cold observables (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079030/what-is-cold-observable-in-context-of-angular-httpclient). Since `httpClient` is a cold observable, it will make the request for each call and you don't need to worry about unsubscribing afterward. The main difference between your two methods is when the http request is made. In the observable method, the request won't be made until `.subscribe` is called. In the promise version, the request will be made immediately. I agree with @kasperlauge that, in most cases, observables should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in most cases where you can use promises, observables can do it better! One key advantage of observables is that they can be canceled (by unsubscibing to the subscription). That is a feature which is also useful when only returning a single value.

Further more all the operator functions of observables handling multiple parallel async requests is far easier to use than to manually brew some promise handling together.

If you want to avoid unsubscribing to trivial observables/subscriptions, you can use the take(1) operator function which makes sure you do not get unexpected function call (if you forgot to unsubscribe).

This would be done as:

```
this.assessmentService.getAssessmentById(this.assessmentId)
 .pipe(take(1))
 .subscribe(result => 
 {
    this.assessment = result;
 });
```

If only simple async tasks is needed, rxjs can be unnecessary and promises can be used instead. The advantages of using promises from my perspective is the cleaner syntax using async/await and the native support (not needing to rely on a third-party library).

Comment: It seems your choice of words is very subjective: "manually brew". I am not advocating against Observables, but you make it almost sound like using Promises is bad practice.

Comment: Well yeah it is my opinion and of course very subjective. But I would say that if you have chosen to import the rxjs library in your project it is bad practice to use promises, as observables can handle the async stuff better. (unless of course you find a case where they cannot). That said I would not say that it is neccesary to import the rxjs library, if only simple async stuff is being done :)

Comment: But I feel you address the issue from one side, only naming advantages that fit your opinion, enforced with some wording to put Promises in a bad light. Why not mention some advantages of Promises in your answer?

Comment: I see that and have tried to elaborate a bit on promises (in my opinion)