# Angular generic handleStatus function and Primeng Message weird behavior

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to display the following component like so:

```
<p-messages
  [(value)]="messages"
  [enableService]="toastEnabled"
  [closable]="false"
></p-messages>
```

Where toastEnabled and messages are both variables declared in my Products component like so:

```
export class ProductsComponent {
  cart$: Observable<Product[]> = this.store
    .select(selectCart)
    .pipe(tap((cart) => console.log(cart)));
  messages: Message[] = [];
  toastEnabled: boolean = false;
  products$: Observable<Product[]> = this.store
    .select(selectProducts)
    .pipe(tap((products) => console.log(products)));
  constructor(
    private walmartService: WalmartService,
    private store: Store<IAppState>
  ) {}

  private handleViewStatusAndToast<T>(
    selector: MemoizedSelector<IAppState, T>,
    descriptor: string
  ): void {
    const status$ = this.store.select(selector).pipe(
      skipWhile((status) => status !== FetchStatus.Loading),
      take(2)
    );

    status$
      .pipe(find((status) => status === FetchStatus.Loading))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.toastEnabled = true;

        this.messages = [
          {
            severity: 'warn',
            summary: 'Loading',
            detail: `${descriptor} is loading...`,
          },
        ];
      });

    status$
      .pipe(find((status) => status === FetchStatus.Success))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.toastEnabled = true;

        this.messages = [
          {
            severity: 'success',
            summary: 'Success',
            detail: `Successfully loaded ${descriptor}!`,
          },
        ];
      });

    status$
      .pipe(find((status) => status === FetchStatus.Failure))
      .subscribe((error) => {
        this.toastEnabled = true;

        this.messages = [
          { severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error...' },
        ];
      });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.handleViewStatusAndToast(selectCartStatus, 'cart');
    this.store.dispatch({ type: '[Products Component] Load Products' });
    this.store.dispatch({ type: '[Cart Component] Load Cart' });
  }
```

The message component is showing along with text but it's color is red and it's message is 'Error...' which is the last status and which can't be possible because the data is showing as well so there's no way an error occurred.

Anyone know why?

Side note - Anyone know if this is the Primeng is the component library I should be focused on? I'm just jumping back into Angular and want to know if I should spend my time learning another one instead

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Observables don't work like that.
But don't worry I'm here to explain how you should refactor your handleViewSta... function.

##### Subscription

First, when you're subscribing to any observable in your code. The subscription will not end unless something triggers the complete event.
This means that when you subscribe to an observable, you aren't willing to subscribe multiple times to the same observable.

##### Asynchronous

You should definitely take a look at the async pipe and behavior.
[async/await vs observables vs promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883785/observable-subscribe-vs-promise-with-async-await/55883849#55883849)

##### Your code

This means that your function should not subscribe multiple times to the status observable because you don't want to retrieve possible different statuses but only one status per product or cart or any other object.

**skipWhile** has absolutely no sense here.
SkipWhile operator according to [rxjs documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/skipWhile), says you're returning only statuses that are of type "Loading".

```
const status$ = this.store.select(selector);

status$.subscribe((status) => {
  this.toastEnabled = true;

  if (status === FetchStatus.Loading) {
    this.messages = [
      {
        severity: 'warn',
        summary: 'Loading',
        detail: `${descriptor} is loading...`,
      },
    ];
  } else if (status === FetchStatus.Success) {
    this.messages = [
      {
        severity: 'success',
        summary: 'Success',
        detail: `Successfully loaded ${descriptor}!`,
      },
    ];
  } else if (status === FetchStatus.Failure) {
    this.messages = [
      { severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error...' },
    ];
  }
});
```

This is quick written code and can be improved by several ways (like using a switch case, ...).

##### Remember

Because an observable is asynchronous, you have to make sure the subscription is made before the data being loaded.

##### Why even observables ?

In your code, I believe you're trying to load a cart and it's products. In that case, as I mentionned in the asynchronous tab, you are willing to use a promise.

If you want to use an observable, take a look at the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). It allows you to display data as an observable is still retrieving them asynchronously.

**What you really should be doing is only use an async pipe to display asynchronously our data into your view.**

Hope this helps a little bit more ;). I highly recommend watching some of fireship youtube tutorials. (link down below)

[rxjs observables guide](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)
[rxjs quick start by fireship](https://youtu.be/2LCo926NFLI?si=NGVhadZGQwK2aiIx)

Comment: observables aren't inherently asynchronous, they can represent both async and sync operations

Comment: Absolutely! You're right. Altough since you will be rendering your value in a template, I would reccomend using an async behavior by using the async pipe.